# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while scrolling TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

This issue is freaking my out. I know many others have already posted about it but none were relevant to my problem.

My goal is to show the elements from a `NSMutableArray` into a `UITableViewController`.
In order to do that, I've declared the array in the .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * departures;
```

---

In the `-viewDidLoad` of the `UITableViewController`, I allocated it:

```
self.departures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

---

During a xml parsing process I add the elements to the departures array:

```
myDeparture = [DepartureModel createDepartureWithScheduled:scheduledData
                                                  Expected:expectedData
                                                      Town:townData
                                                      Stop:stopData
                                                  Platform:platformData];
[self.departures addObject:myDeparture];
```

And finally I load data in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellPartenza";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

DepartureModel *dep = [self.departures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = dep.scheduled; //****** ERROR HERE
cell.detailTextLabel.text = dep.town;
```

I'd like to know why I get the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` anytime I try to scroll the `tableView`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the line that crashes and inspecting the content of dep?  My guess is that `dep.scheduled` is garbage - or nil.

Comment: that's exactly what is happening! I cannot understand why the MutableArray loses its data after scrolling. At the first loading the data are displayed proprerly instead.

Comment: It doesn't look like the the mutable array is losing the data.  It looks like the DepartureModel is losing the data.  Can you show the code for `DepartureModel`?

Comment: How do you store `scheduled` property? is it `strong`?

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint so you can see precisely where the error occurs?

Comment: does `self.departures` actually contains the expected item count?

Comment: SOLVED. Thanks to kovpas! it was enough defining the property scheduled as STRONG. Thank you all, I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW!!

Comment: @kovpas put your comment that correctly diagnoses the problem in an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @JeremyP done. Glad it's sorted out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if `DepartyreModel`'s `scheduled` property is declared as `strong`.

Strong reference increases retain count, so when you assign autoreleased object to it, it's not deallocated in the end of runloop.